# Формирование сообщения рукопожатия

Tags: c#, .net, torrent

На странице спецификации протокола [`BitTorrent`](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Handshake), сказано, что сообщение рукопожатия, должно быть отправлено первым, после подключения. И указано следущяя структура этого сообщения:

> **Handshake**
>
> The handshake is a required message and must be the first message
>   transmitted by the client. It is (49+len(pstr)) bytes long.
>
> ```
> handshake: <pstrlen><pstr><reserved><info_hash><peer_id>
> ```
>
> - pstrlen: string length of , as a single raw byte
> - pstr: string identifier of the protocol
> - reserved: eight (8) reserved bytes. All current implementations use all zeroes. Each bit in these bytes can be used to change the behavior
>     of the protocol. An email from Bram suggests that trailing bits should
>     be used first, so that leading bits may be used to change the meaning
>     of trailing bits.
> - info_hash: 20-byte SHA1 hash of the info key in the metainfo file. This is the same info_hash that is transmitted in tracker requests.
> - peer_id: 20-byte string used as a unique ID for the client. This is usually the same peer_id that is transmitted in tracker requests (but
>     not always e.g. an anonymity option in Azureus).

Так вот, я подумал что сообщение должно формироваться следущим образом:

```
const string protocol = "BitTorrent protocol";

string request = $"<{protocol.Length}>" +           // <pstrlen>
                 $"<{protocol}>" +                  // <pstr>
                 "<        >" +                     // <reserved>
                 $"<{torrentFile.GetInfoHash()}>" + // <info_hash>
                 "<-AZ206088->";                    // <peer_id>
```

Однако это не работает, т.к. при отправке сообщения одному из пиров, он не отвечает, т.е. не шлет в ответ ничего, думаю я не правильно сформировал сообщение рукопожатия.

Как правильно сформировать сообщение?

Comment: Я, может, вне контекста что-то не так понял, но ведь `pstrlen` должен быть передан как `single raw byte`, а Вы строку пихаете

Answer (score 1):

**Все строковые константы начисто скопированы из вопроса.**

Судя по протоколу можно сделать так:

1) Получаем байты из строки протокола. В [доках](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding) написано, что всё в ASCII

```
const string protocol = "BitTorrent protocol";
var content = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(protocol);
```

2) Создаём массив нужного размера

```
var message = new byte[49 + content.Length];
```

3) Записываем байтовую длину строки протокола

```
int currentPosition = 0;
message[currentPosition++] = (byte) content.Length;
```

3) Записываем само байтовое представление

```
Array.Copy(content, 0, message, currentPosition, content.Length);
currentPosition += content.Length;
```

4) Оставляем 8 пустых байт по воле доков с:

```
currentPosition += 8;
```

5) Копируем 20-байтовый хэш

```
Array.Copy(torrentfile.GetInfoHashBytes(), 0, message, currentPosition, 20);
urrentPosition += 20;
```

6) Получаем байтовое представление peer строки и записываем его
*Если вы следуете Azureus-style, то у вас указан неверный peer, т.к. этот стиль подразумевает:*

> '-', two characters for client id, four ascii digits for version number, '-', followed by random numbers.

```
const string peer = "-AZ206088-";
var peerTextContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(peer);

Array.Copy(peerTextContent, 0, message, currentPosition, peerTextContent.Length);
currentPosition += peerTextContent.Length;
```

7) В протоколе сказано, что peer должен состоять ровно из 20 байт, и если не хватает, то заполнить случайными числами, а т.к. у нас нет лишних байт в массиве, то мы заполняем его до конца, т.к. это будет соответствовать тому, сколько байт не хватило в `peer`

```
new Random().NextBytes(message.AsSpan(currentPosition));
```

8) Отправляем наш массив `message` куда нужно :3

Comment: Мне 39 хостов bp 39 по `UDP` и `TCP` не отправили ответ.

Comment: Может быть что-то не так с данными? Все строки в моём ответе скопированы из вопроса

Comment: @ヒミコ, кстати говоря, протокол говорит, что peer должен выглядеть как -##****-, где # - цифра,а * - буква. _Azureus-style uses the following encoding: '-', two characters for client id, four ascii digits for version number, '-', followed by random numbers._

Comment: Длинна сообщения должна быть 68 если строка protocol не изменена (а тут явно больше), значит что-то не так, потому что в моём варианте массив всего на 68 создаётся)

Comment: У меня 68 размер: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apy6h.png, но они все равно не дают отклик.

Comment: А какой вам приходит ответ? Потому что вроде как должен быть код ошибки в случае чего. Если верить вот этой [pdf](http://dandylife.net/docs/BitTorrent-Protocol.pdf). Если не приходит ничего, то возможно что где-то в другом месте есть проблема

Comment: Вообще ничего не приходит, единственное что я вижу, это доступные байты 0. Но один из пиров все таки раз на раз откликается, но отдает BitField

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98254/discussion-between-kamushek-and-).